# Data retrieves by get extra but only first element in array can set to a TextView in second Activity

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I have populated a Long array in activity A and pass it to Activity B by putExtra() method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsAcitivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("bonds", bounds);
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
    }
```

And in the activity B I've retrieve them:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
bounds2 = extras.getLongArray("bonds");
```

Then I want to put each element in array in different TextView so I did this:

```
TextView tvb1;
TextView tvb2;
long[] bounds2=new long[10];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    bounds2 = extras.getLongArray("bonds");

    tvb1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWageDetailVal01);
    tvb1.setTypeface(droidnaskh_regular);
    String str=String.format("%,d",bounds2[0]);
    tvb1.setText(str);

    tvb2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWageDetailVal02);
    tvb2.setTypeface(droidnaskh_regular);
    str=String.format("%,d",bounds2[1]);
    tvb2.setText(str);

    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(bounds2[1]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
```

Now the TextView tvb1's text sets to bounds2[0] value but tvb2 will not! Even the Toast message shows proper value of bounds2[1] but the TextView's text wont set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true way to pass value. Use the code below:

class A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, classa.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("value 1", "String value 1");
bundle.putString("value 2","String value 2");
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

class B:

```
Bundle getData = getIntent().getExtras();
String value1= getData .getString("String value 1");
String value2= getData .getString("String value 2");
textview.setText(value1);
```